# How much cash can you carry on a flight within the European Union?

Tags: air-travel, europe, money, international-travel

Is there any specific limit of money you can carry on cash while flying from one European Union country to another?

Comment: I missed the "L" in "flight" and had a bit of a head-scratch moment.

Comment: Be aware that some airports have sniffer dogs that can detect large amounts of cash.

Comment: @DJClayworth How does that work ? If they can detect large amounts of cash surely they can detect smaller amounts too.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There seems to be no limit as such.

However if you carry more than 10'000 €, you [might have to declare it](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/carry/alcohol-tobacco-cash/index_en.htm) depending on the country.

For example in [Germany](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Travel-within-the-EU/Restrictions/Cash/cash_node.html), you are to declare it when orally asked to do so. For the [UK](https://www.gov.uk/bringing-cash-into-uk) on the other hand, there seems to be no need to do so.

So if you consider taking more than 10'000 €, you should check the rules for the specific country you are flying to.

Comment: Very good answer! I accept it, as it answers exactly the point. I would say that the rules from the departure country should also be considered.

Comment: True, remember reading a story about some Chinese money launderers who used to buy the old coins thrown away by Bundesbank in bulk, get them to China and repair and then bring them back to Germany in chunks of 9999 EUR

Comment: Similar for the Czech Republic. Remember that cheques and valuables (stocks) can also qualify as money.

Comment: In fact, anything that is "equivalent of" 10,000 and can be used as "money" - you should be ready to provide source of funds. This includes stocks, bonds, cashier's checks, precious metals, etc.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on another answer, it's worth pointing out that for most countries you may carry as much as you like, you just have to declare it and should expect to be questioned about it.

Comment: @yo' I don't think  cheques made out to a named party have to be reported. Perhaps interestingly, imports of gold bullion are specifically excluded from US requirements (but gold coins are required to be reported).

Answer (score 21):

Assuming a maximum luggage allowance of 20kg, and that the [weight of 1m EUR is about 2kg](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/8678979.stm). Then we are talking about 10 million Euros. :D

Of course that is assuming that you are too poor to pay for extra allowance.

Comment: Hopefully the weight was the problem :)

Comment: that is a good answer ;-)

Comment: Great idea, but you'll never make 20 million Euros with those math skills. :)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni fixed...bah...you could have done the edit yourself :P It was correct to an order of magnitude, which is the maths I was taught.

Comment: Funny but it might be useful to make the most important point (namely that there is no general limit) explicit and to quote relevant sources.

Comment: I can't imagine someone giving up a large amount of money as main luggage, so better to calculate regular luggage, and every possible pocket.

Comment: **This is a very misleading answer.**

Comment: @tohecz How so?

Comment: @Relaxed Well, maybe not misleading (that was a bit too strong, sorry for that). But without citation of reliable sources, I can't believe it, especially since the observation I made during my journeys is different..

Comment: @tohecz Not really, it's just saying the same than drat above, only in a slightly obscure humorous way. Where did you observe something different?

Comment: "I don't believe you" isn't an acceptable reason to call an answer misleading.

Comment: can take several suitcases, on sas up to 5 or even more with premium membership

Answer (score 9):

Apart of regulations [mentioned by drat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26119/727), EU also has anti-money laundering laws. They apply regardless if you travel internationally or not.

> [The EU directive 2005/60/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32005L0060:EN:HTML) "on the prevention of the use of the
>   financial system for the purpose of money laundering and terrorist
>   financing" tries to prevent such crime by requiring banks, real estate
>   agents and many more companies to investigate and report usage of cash
>   in excess of €15,000

How this directive is implemented in practice depends on each member state.

Comment: This seems unrelated to the travel aspect. I didn't downvote it because it does not seem incorrect but how does it address the question and why did it get more votes than drat's answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the complementary answer. It is quite useful to know that there is a rule on that. Accepting the "original" answer, but also very grateful with this.

Comment: The laws in individual countries on the use of cash for payments can be more restrictive. For example it is illegal to pay for goods or services in cash of EUR 1000 or more in Italy. In Greece the limit is EUR 1500. See http://www.europe-consommateurs.eu/en/consumer-topics/buying-of-goods-and-services/cash-payment-limitations/ for details on all EU countries.

Comment: Note also that this doesn't prevent you travelling with any amount you like, it just suggests that you're likely to be questioned about it (either at the time, later, or both). Your cash is your own property and you're more than entitled to carry as much of it with you as you wish.

Answer (score 4):

On a recent trip to Greece (3rd August 2015) I was stopped at Gatwick airport South for the random bag search and was asked about the cash I had in my wallet. It was 1500 euros plus £300 UK.   I was told that part of the Euros could be confiscated as it was 'over limit'. after a behind the scenes discussion between customs officials I was allowed to 'keep it'. That was purely personal experience and I don't know where this approach came from. I too thought there was no limit in the EU.

Comment: Wow, weird! Glad to read that at least you did not have to pay anything. Did they mention what rule they were following? Since this should happen only if you had >10K euros. Could it be related to be coming from UK and, thus, no Schengen area?

Comment: I was offered no further explanation than 'its the rules' and it is not always a good ploy to question Customs lest they think you are arguing. I assume it was an error and I probably would have argued if they had tried to take the money. I did tell them I was going to Greece and cash was recommended by HM GOv. First time ever this has happened.

Answer (score 3):

What nonsense. In the UK there is no limit to amount of cash you can take out to another European state. The treasury department currently have abandoned restrictions although this can be changed at any time.

However beware POCA (proceeds of crime act) and money laundering act. This means that any large amount can be seized by police, customs or UK border. They have a time limit to put you in front of a magistrate who will decide if you can keep it or not.

My advice be respectful and honest. Prove where money came from (eg bank receipt, statement), prove what money is for (eg expensive hotel car, holiday home charges etc) with paperwork and they should let you go. More than say 10 or 12 grand may be a problem but no one will state how much. The officer can decide. Good luck!

Comment: +1 because you're very new. Please be sure to include the relevant authorities (links to EU regulations in this case) when referring to them in an answer.

Comment: When you say "What nonsense", what are you referring to? Please bear in mind that we're a question and answer site, not a discussion forum, so posts should be directed at answering the question at the top of the page, not discussing issues with other posters.

Answer (score 2):

With in the EU there is a freedom of capital moment. However, having said the above you need to know that up to €10.000 cash no questions are asked. For larger amounts like €50.000 or €100.000+ you would be asked to prove the source of that cash. (money laundering regulations). Also you would be asked the reason for moving this kind of money in cash.

As long as you have a legitimate source for that money and a legitimate reason to take that money in another country, I don't see a problem.

Kindly note that for Tax purposes you will have to declare the movement of cash to the customs if you don't declare the cash at the customs and you get caught (most probably you will), you will be in serious troubles. You might even spend a night or two in jail.

Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a reporting limit of 10.000 EUR when entering from outside.

The rules which are actually often misquoted, does not require you to report any cash travelling within the EU

Comment: Hi! Please, do you have sources of this statements? The rules of the Prague airport seem to be different, because even on the in-Schengen terminal, you are required to report 10k+ EUR cash possession.

Comment: That's what the EU rules mandate but it's not forbidden for individual member states to add additional requirements.

Comment: If you're going to claim that the rules are "often misquoted", you really ought to provide a link to the actual rules.